# Pandas self join on a single column with no duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to find unique rows, where unique is in the sense of two "identical" columns?

```
>>> d = pandas.DataFrame([['A',1],['A',2],['A',3],['B',1],['B',4],['B',2]], columns = ['col_a','col_b'])
>>> d  col_a  col_b
0     A      1
1     A      2
2     A      3
3     B      1
4     B      4
5     B      2

>>> d.merge(d,left_on='col_b',right_on='col_b')  col_a_x  col_b col_a_y
0       A      1       A
1       A      1       B
2       B      1       A
3       B      1       B
4       A      2       A
5       A      2       B
6       B      2       A
7       B      2       B
8       A      3       A
9       B      4       B


>>> d_desired  
0       A      1       A
1       A      1       B
3       B      1       B
4       A      2       A
5       A      2       B
7       B      2       B
8       A      3       A
9       B      4       B
```

But I would like to drop the duplicate entries - e.g `B      1       A,B      2       A`
I would later want to group by the two columns, thus I need somehow to always drop the same "duplicate", meaning if I dropped `B1A` I should also drop `B2A` and not `A2B`.

Comment: kindly post ur expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you :

```
M = d.merge(d,left_on='col_b',right_on='col_b')

#find rows where col first is greater than col last
#and not equal to each other
cond = (M.col_a_x > M.col_a_y) & (M.col_a_x != M.col_a_y)
#filter out the row
M.loc[~cond]
```